# Oracle performance tuning order by is taking time

Tags: oracle, performance

Am having query,in which two fields and getting as output `pps_id` and `total_weight`. Here `pps_id` is the column from the table and `total_weight` we are calculating from inner query. after doing all process in query we are order by the query by total weight. Its taking more cost and response.Is there any way to improve this query performance.

```
    SELECT PPS_ID, TOTAL_WEIGHT
  FROM (  SELECT PPS_ID, TOTAL_WEIGHT
            FROM (SELECT pps_id,
                         ROUND (
                              (  (  (60 * name_pct_match / 100)
                                  + prs_weight
                                  + year_weight
                                  + dt_weight)
                               / 90)
                            * 100)
                            total_weight
                    FROM (SELECT pps_id,
                                 ROUND (func_compare_name ('aaaa',
                                                           UPPER (name_en),
                                                           ' ',
                                                           60))
                                    name_pct_match,
                                 DECODE (prs_nationality_id, 99, 15, 0)
                                    prs_weight,
                                 10 mother_weight,
                                 100 total_attrib_weight,
                                 CASE
                                    WHEN TO_NUMBER (
                                            TO_CHAR (birth_date, 'yyyy')) =
                                            1986
                                    THEN
                                       5
                                    ELSE
                                       0
                                 END
                                    year_weight,
                                 CASE
                                    WHEN     TO_CHAR (
                                                TO_DATE ('12-JAN-86',
                                                         'DD-MON-RRRR'),
                                                'dd') =
                                                TO_CHAR (birth_date, 'dd')
                                         AND TO_CHAR (
                                                TO_DATE ('12-JAN-86',
                                                         'DD-MON-RRRR'),
                                                'mm') =
                                                TO_CHAR (birth_date, 'mm')
                                    THEN
                                       10
                                    WHEN TO_DATE ('12-JAN-86', 'DD-MON-RRRR') BETWEEN   birth_date
                                                                                      - 6
                                                                                  AND   birth_date
                                                                                      + 6
                                    THEN
                                       8
                                    WHEN TO_DATE ('12-JAN-86', 'DD-MON-RRRR') BETWEEN   birth_date
                                                                                      - 28
                                                                                  AND   birth_date
                                                                                      + 28
                                    THEN
                                       5
                                    WHEN TO_DATE ('12-JAN-86', 'DD-MON-RRRR') BETWEEN   birth_date
                                                                                      - 90
                                                                                  AND   birth_date
                                                                                      + 90
                                    THEN
                                       3
                                    ELSE
                                       0
                                 END
                                    dt_weight
                            FROM individual_profile
                           WHERE     birth_date = '12-JAN-86'
                                 AND IS_ACTIVE = 1
                                 AND gender_id = 1
                                 AND ROUND (func_compare_name ('aaa',
                                                               UPPER (name_en),
                                                               ' ',
                                                               60)) > 20))
           WHERE TOTAL_WEIGHT >= 100
        ORDER BY total_weight DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

i have tried by splitting the query and put values in temp tables and tried but it also taking time. I want to improve the performance of the query

Comment: Post the execution plan.

Comment: The "order by" makes the query much slower because the database must calculate all rows so it can sort them correctly. Without the "order by", just 10 arbitrary rows are processed before the "rownum" filter kicks in. Therefore, the slowdown is inherent to the type of query you have.

Comment: Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 350  Bytes: 502  Cardinality: 20                      
    5 COUNT STOPKEY                  
        4 VIEW VISION_APP. Cost: 300  Bytes: 502  Cardinality: 20              
            3 SORT ORDER BY  Cost: 300  Bytes: 502  Cardinality: 20          
                2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE VISION_APP.INDIVIDUAL_PROFILE Cost: 260  Bytes: 502  Cardinality: 20      
                    1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX VISION_APP.IDX_INDIVPROF_BIRTHDATE Cost: 260  Cardinality: 20

Comment: WHERE TOTAL_WEIGHT >= 100
        ORDER BY total_weight DESC these two things taking more time is there any option to perform better with these. any hint ? as these are computed values we cant create any index on this....

Comment: @FrancisJohn - instead of adding comments with the execution plan - Edit the question and include it directly in the question.  Also format as best as you can - improved readability will produce more results.

Comment: Newbies can't even edit their own questions; and it's rather hard to figure out how the execution plan should look like.

Comment: computed column total weight is taking more cost since we are doing order by in that.. is there anyway to put a hint or any virtual indexes in 11g.

Comment: Do you have an index on `individual_profile(birth_date, is_active, gender_id)`?

Comment: yes that three columns are indexed.